# Asp.Net: Can't $find("ModalPopupExtenderID") when using ScriptManagerProxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

(I'm sorry if my English is not good)

I has a Ajax ModalPopupExtender as below code:

```
 <cc1:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="modalFormPopup" OkControlID="btnOKFake" ClientIDMode="Static"
        Drag="true" TargetControlID="btnFake" BehaviorID="modalFormPopupBID" Enabled="true"
        BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG" PopupControlID="pnFake">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnFake" Text="Show Popup" Style="display: none" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOKFake" Text="Show Popup" Style="display: none" />
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnFake" Style="display: none"></asp:Panel>
```

And I'll process it in my javascript code as below.

```
var modal = $find("modalFormPopupBID");
modal.set_PopupControlID("HDKHdialog");
modal.set_PopupDragHandleControlID("PopupHeaderHDKH");
modal.set_CancelControlID("lbtnCancelHDKH");
modal.initialize();
modal.show();
```

**My problem is**:
- When I use

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="abc123" runat="server">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

in my content page and don't use ToolkitScriptManager in Master Page, **it's ok**.
- But when I use ToolkitScriptManager in my Master Page as

```
<body style="min-height: 700px;">
<form runat="server" id="Form1">
   <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ToolkitScriptManager1">
   </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

and use ScriptManagerProxy in Content Page as

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server" ID="ScriptManagerProxy1"></asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

everything is good but i can't execute `var modal = $find("modalFormPopupBID");` it's always return null, that mean can't find my Ajax ModalPopupExtended. I spend many time to fix it, but it still return null. Whether it is bug of Ajax toolkit ?

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed it**. In my Page_Load, in code behind, i call javascript method named is ExpandCache() by code:

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), "PageLoad", "ExpandCache()", true);

When i open Developer Tools in Chrome, javascript code block appear in end of page look like

```
ExpandCache()(function() {var fn = function() {$get("ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField").value = '';Sys.Application.remove_init(fn);};Sys.Application.add_init(fn);})();Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
$create(Sys.Extended.UI.ModalPopupBehavior, {"BackgroundCssClass":"ModalPopupBG","Drag":true,"OkControlID":"MainContent_btnOKFake","PopupControlID":"MainContent_pnFake","dynamicServicePath":"/Module_GioKhoaHoc/ModuleGioKhoaHocTeacherView.aspx","id":"modalID"}, null, null, $get("MainContent_btnFake"));
```

if i don't use the above code in code behind, the javascript code block look like:

```
(function() {var fn = function() {$get("ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField").value = '';Sys.Application.remove_init(fn);};Sys.Application.add_init(fn);})();Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
$create(Sys.Extended.UI.ModalPopupBehavior, {"BackgroundCssClass":"ModalPopupBG","Drag":true,"OkControlID":"MainContent_btnOKFake","PopupControlID":"MainContent_pnFake","dynamicServicePath":"/Module_GioKhoaHoc/ModuleGioKhoaHocTeacherView.aspx","id":"modalID"}, null, null, $get("MainContent_btnFake"));
```

And everything work perfectly ! I don't understand ?

Thanks for reading. Best regard !